# Sellers use iOS device scan buyers' credit card to finish payment

Tags: ios, paypal, payment, credit-card

I wanna develop an App used by sellers. The App should be able to scan the buyers' credit card and finish payment with signature or secret code. Can any API help me do it?

remember: only sellers have iOS device, buyers only have to take a credit card

Comment: you mean like square? https://squareup.com/ca/reader

Comment: square seems like used by customers , i mean to be add the function to my app . Function is : used by sellers , who scan buyers' credit card and make him pay. Not the way that buyers scan their own card and pay. Must used by Sellers!!!! @user3802077

Comment: You realise that there is just a little bit of legislation and regulation involved if you as much as touch credit cards? Do you think you have a legal department that is up to it?

Comment: I know , so i prefer to use some third-party sdk to do it . @gnasher729

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal and Square offer systems to take care of this. They've both been doing it for a while, so their APIs are fairly robust.

I think PayPal is in more countries as its been on the go for longer, but I don't know about the price difference between them and Square for the fees or the price of the card reader.

Comment: are you sure they release some API to us ? how can i find it ? @MikeCoats

Comment: @JJ.Yuan Details of Square's iOS API are here, https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/register-api-overview/ , and PayPal's are here, https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK  . The PayPal one looks pretty good as it looks like you don't need any extra hardware, as their example screenshot shows them using the camera to scan the card.

Comment: are you sure Square or PayPal's can help me with these : used by sellers , who scan buyers' credit card and make him pay. Not the way that buyers scan their own card and pay.   Must used by Sellers!!!!!!

Comment: @JJ.Yuan I've not tried it personally, but the top image on the PayPal iOS ask GitHub repo shows a store checkout procedure occurring and the API docs here, https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md , walk through everything required to accept a single payment from someone's card on an iPhone. I suggest trying it out and seeing what it's like to use for yourself. I'd be surprised if you could not make it fit your use case. PayPal have been in the payment business for a long time.